# Cell Array String from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, string, matlab, numpy, cell-array

I have a .mat dataset obtained from Matlab that have some data, including an 1920x1 Cell Array String stored as follow:

```
"sample1"
"sample2"
"sample3"
```

I need to import it in Python as list or array. I already got my mat using `loadmat` from scipy and works fine importing other type of data, but I'm facing issues trying to import cell string array:

```
import scipy.io as spio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mat = spio.loadmat('Dati.mat', squeeze_me=True)
FD_Labels_cell = mat_char['FD_Labels']
list= np.asarray(FD_Labels_cell, dtype=object).tolist()
print(list)
```

output:

```
[[MatlabOpaque([(b'', b'MCOS', b'string', array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
             dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])], [MatlabOpaque([(b'', b'MCOS', b'string', array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         2],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
             dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])], [MatlabOpaque([(b'', b'MCOS', b'string', array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         3],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
             dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])], [MatlabOpaque([(b'', b'MCOS', b'string', array([[3707764736]
```

and output goes on.
I don't know why I get this kind of output and I'm unable to get cells from my Matlab file.

Comment: `MatlabOpaque` means the cell contains MATLAB objects that `loadmat` can't convert to python equivalents.

Comment: So it's incompatible. Well, thanks!

Comment: Could you convert your cell array to a `table`, then write it to a csv (`writetable`)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a cell array, it is a string. It is a different data type. Matlab has 3 different data types for text:

1. char array.  Looks like `'this is a char'` or `[`a b';'c d']`. Note the single quotes and square brackets). This is sometimes called a string in the docs for historical reasons.
2. cell string, which is literally just a cell array of char arrays.  Looks like `{'a b'}`.  Note the single quotes and curly brackets.  This goes by several names, cell array of strings, cell string, or cellstr.
3. string array.  Looks like `"a b"` or `["a b", "c"]`. Note the double quotes. This is completely different data type than the first two, and is also much, much newer so it is apparently not supported by scipy.

If you converted it to a cell array with the `cellstr` function in MATLAB before saving it you should be able to load it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the mat file with variables in a wrong format.
Convert the format to cellstr in matlab, export the file and then read it using scipy. Then you can apply df functions on it by creating a dataframe.
I converted it to cellstr, export again from matlab and then read using scipy and it worked. reference can be found on my git repo: https://github.com/fahnub/matlab-datetime-data-extraction

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).